# More than one connection opened in MongoDB using NodeJS and Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to Node and MongoDB, so please forgive me if I sound too naive.

I have a DB class that creates a connection to MongoDB

**db.service.js**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const fs = require("fs");
const dbConfigs = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("/configs.json"));
const dbHost = dbConfigs.DB_HOST;
const dbName = dbConfigs.DB_NAME;
const dbPort = dbConfigs.DB_PORT;
const dbUrl = "mongodb://" + dbHost + ":" + dbPort + "/" + dbName;
const dbOptions = {
    useNewUrlParser: true
};

let dbConnection = mongoose.createConnection(dbUrl, dbOptions);
exports.getConnection = () => {
    if (dbConnection)
        return dbConnection;
}

exports.closeConnection = () => {
    if (dbConnection)
        return dbConnection.close();
}
```

Next I have another module that creates a Schema for MongoDB

**schema.js**

```
const connection = require("./db.service").getConnection();
const Schema = require("mongoose").Schema;

const SampleSchema = new Schema({...})

exports.Sample = connection.model("Sample", SampleSchema);
```

Then I have another module that makes use of this Schema to save objects

**logger.js**

```
const Sample = require("./schema").Sample;

exports.log = () => {

let body = {....};
let sampleObj = new Sample(body);
return sampleObj.save(sampleObj);
```

The Main module

**Main.js**

```
const logger = require("./logger");

for (let i=0; i < 100; i++) {
    logger.log();
}
```

When I run `node Main.js`, everything is saved, but when I check the MongoDB with the command `db.serverStatus.connections`, I see 6 connections open.

I don't know how it's getting there. I know the command `mongo` itself keep a connection open, but where are the other 5 connections coming from?

I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29998964/why-my-nodejs-program-opens-multiple-connections-to-mongo-using-native-driver), which seems to suggest that Mongoose opens 5 connections for an application, but my application is firing just one transaction, where is the need to open 5 connection then? Couldn't it be done with just one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mongoose is managing the connections itself; it tries to optimize the speed of the request.

You are seeing it like you are using only one transaction, but behind the scene mongoose is probably doing much more than you expect.

---

You can modify the number of connection mongoose can open using the parameter `poolSize`.

---

**Example** :

```
const dbOptions = {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    poolSize: 1,
};
```

---

Try it with `poolSize` equals to 1 and see how much time it takes to execute your transaction, you'll have your answer.

Comment: Thanks!! That indeed answered my question.